CrossWordSearch 3
This is a crosswordsearch, a puzzle that's part crossword and part word search.
In the puzzle, shade in some of the squares such that the remaining squares form a crossword puzzle that satisfies the set of given clues. Words run horizontally and vertically, and may run forwards or backwards. Each word in the final crossword has at least 3 letters.
Good luck!

Text version
P F E U D F A
R A T K O O B
E P R A H S C
Y B U R N I D
A N S S D O E
P Y T H O N F
H O M A G E L
O J U R O R P
N O T P E D A

Clues
An instrument
A programming language
A programming language
A programming language
A programming language
A programming language
A programming language
Some programmers are
Senior programmers are
Senior programmers get
Senior programmers have a lot
Senior programmers important date
Helps to learn programming
You feel when the code compiles
You feel like when the code compiles
Catchphrase, when the code doesn't compile?
____ free
Standards org.


I believe the grid is:

 


And the answers to the clues, hopefully in the intended order ([B] if backwards in grid):

An instrument  - HARP
A programming language - PYTHON
A programming language - C SHARP [B]
A programming language - RUBY [B]
A programming language - ABC
A programming language - RAKU [B]
A programming language -  RUST
Some programmers are - NERD [B]
Senior programmers are - ADEPT
Senior programmers get - AGE
Senior programmers have a lot - PAY [B]
Senior programmers important date - DUE [B]
Helps to learn programming - BOOK [B]
You feel when the code compiles - JOY [B]
You feel like when the code compiles - GOD [B]
Catchphrase, when the code doesn't compile? - DOH
____ free - BPA
Standards org. - ISO [B]


rot13(lbh'er pybfr, uvag: gur nafjre gb lbhe zvffvat pyhr vf "ocn serr", lbh'yy unir gb fuhssyr n pbhcyr nafjref nebhaq)

I think the missing language is rot13(ncy, hc sebz gur obggbz evtug pbeare)

@ChrisCudmore possibly, but that then creates the two letters 'RP' which wouldn't fit in the crossword as everything is at least 3 letters, so might be right but then more reshuffling required

The missing language is ehfg

@samm82 oh no I'm an idiot, I had it and thought I'd already written it whoops, guess the catchphrase answer is appropriate here :P

Not a problem; happens to the best of us XD

Looks correct to me!
